# Envers reflection error when updating an ElementCollection with EmbeddedId

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have a model that has a composite key id and a map of strings that is mapped as an element collection.

```
@Entity
@Audited
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class DemoModel {
    @EmbeddedId
    private DemoCompositeKey id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name="demo_model_collection", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name="demo_one", referencedColumnName = "one"),
            @JoinColumn(name="demo_two", referencedColumnName = "two")
    })
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "key_thing")
    @Column(name = "value_thing")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude()
    private Map<String, String> someCollection = new HashMap<>();
}
```

The component key is simple in itself as you can already see from the collection table mapping

```
@Embeddable
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DemoCompositeKey implements Serializable {
    Integer one;
    Integer two;
}
```

And a simple repo.

```
@Repository
public interface DemoRepository extends JpaRepository<DemoModel, DemoCompositeKey> {}
```

This setup has been working without any issues for quite a while, but recently I decided I want to audit this entity and added the @Audited tag and added Hibernate Envers to the project.

Inserting the entity initially does not cause any issues and works as expected. But once I try to update one of the elements of the collection the application errors out with the following message (line breaks added by me for readability:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field 
[java.lang.Integer com.example.demo.DemoCompositeKey.one] by reflection 
for persistent property [com.example.demo.DemoCompositeKey#one] : A; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: 
Error accessing field [java.lang.Integer com.example.demo.DemoCompositeKey.one] 
by reflection for persistent property [com.example.demo.DemoCompositeKey#one] : A
```

So as you can see from the error, it appears that it tries to compare the Map key string against the composite key and of course, fails.

The original production code for `DemoModel` has some additional attributes and it made sense from a modeling perspective for it to have a composite key.

Repo with issue: https://github.com/lances101/spring-boot-envers-issue

It seems like Envers is really having trouble with this. Am I defining the Map improperly? Is it a problem because I'm using a composite key?

**Update 2021/03/17**: swapping for a non-composite primary key does work, but then that is a design change and this is most likely a bug / lacking support of within Envers itself.

Ticket created: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14480